How does a plotly (python) chart appear? Unable to get any visual at all
I've just begun playing around with plotly in python (Windows 10), but I'm unable to get even a simple example to render. I'm sure it's something very basic that I'm overlooking, but haven't found enough info to guess what it might be. Using a dead simple example cribbed from a tutorial:
import plotly.io as pio

fig = dict({
    "data": [{"type": "bar",
              "x": [1, 2, 3],
              "y": [1, 3, 2]}],
    "layout": {"title": {"text": "A Figure Specified By Python Dictionary"}}
})

# To display the figure defined by this dict, use the low-level plotly.io.show function

pio.show(fig)

I've tried running this two ways. From the command line:
python testplot2.py
and also from within vscode using the "Run Python file" icon from the editor window.
What I get is a new Chrome tab (or window if Chrome isn't currently running) which is entirely blank. It has the URL:
http://127.0.0.1:51496/
I'm not sure what process is supposed to be listening on port 51496. Apparently something is because the connection request isn't rejected immediately. The page never finished "loading" but never displays anything. When run from the command line the python process seems to be uninterruptable, at least with a Ctl-C. I'm sure I'm doing something very basic very wrong.

For me it runs in VS Code both as notebook and as py script. The script opens http://127.0.0.1:54873/, which is a local server address which is running de underlying HTML code. The port will vary.
Have you tried Edge or Firefox?

I had to abandon Plotly for a different reason. The parallel coordinates chart was ideal for my purpose, and it's great if you have a lot of traces on the chart (visual clumping). Mine has very few, and the lines are so thin they can barely be seen when the chart is printed or otherwise reduced in size. There are numerous comments on their forum asking for a line_width option, but after almost 4 years it hasn't happened yet. Apparently it was written in a different way that doesn't inherit a lot of global options.
